# PHP Form Builder Class TinyMCE - Raw mode to not escape < and >

Tags: php, class, forms, builder

Im using the [PHP Form Builder Class](http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/) and its TinyMCE implementation . I am then passing it through to a Twig template.

If I enter any bold text into TinyMCE though , when it comes through to the Twig , the special chars are escaped.

So:

```
<strong>im bold</strong>
```

shows in the browser, and the source is

```
&lt;strong&gt;im bold&lt;/strong&gt;
```

I have tried using:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    entity_encoding : "raw"
```

Ive also tried writing a function :

```
function html_chars($text) {
$badchars = array( "&lt;" , "&gt;   ");
$goodchars   = array("<" , ">" );
return str_replace($badchars, $goodchars, $text);
```

}

but that doesn't work either.

any idea on how to stop this replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Twig raw](http://www.twig-project.org/doc/templates.html#escape-e) solved this:

```
{% autoescape true %}
{{ var|raw }} {# var won't be escaped #}
{% endautoescape %}
```